# is get_text() from bs4 different for span tags? Cant remove span tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Whilst making a web scraper i am able to find an scrape the data available.
on 2 fields of data i am able to use the beautifulsoup get_text() to reomve html from the data

but the 3rd fields will not work when i use get_text(). I can get it to give me the whole span tag just not the text inside it.

i have tried different iterations of getting the data all the same, it will give me the whole span tag ie. stuff

Trying to set busnumber to the phone number inside this span tag

```html
<span class="business--telephoneNumber" itemprop="telephone">01430 422826 </span>
```

ive tried

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

data_list=[]
url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=farmer&location=leeds'
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    }
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5);
if site.status_code is 200:
    content = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
    #print(content)
    questions = content.find_all(class_='businessCapsule') 
for question in questions:
        busname = question.find(class_='businessCapsule--name').get_text()
        bustype =   question.find(class_='businessCapsule--classification').get_text()
        busnum = question.find('span', {'itemprop': 'telephone'})
        print(busnum)
        busnumber = busnum.get_text()
        new_data = {"busname": busname, "bustype": bustype, "busnumber": busnumber}
        data_list.append(new_data)
    with open ('selector.csv','w') as file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = ["busname", "bustype", "busnumber"], delimiter = ';')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data_list:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

as well as

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

data_list=[]
url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=farmer&location=leeds'
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    }
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5);
if site.status_code is 200:
    content = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
    #print(content)
    questions = content.find_all(class_='businessCapsule')
    for question in questions:
        busname = question.find(class_='businessCapsule--name').get_text()
        bustype =   question.find(class_='businessCapsule--classification').get_text()
        busnumber = question.find('span', {'itemprop': 'telephone'}).get_text()
        new_data = {"busname": busname, "bustype": bustype, "busnumber": busnumber}
        data_list.append(new_data)
    with open ('selector.csv','w') as file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = ["busname", "bustype", "busnumber"], delimiter = ';')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data_list:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

on both cases the get_text() gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscraper2.py", line 22, in <module>
    busnumber = busnum.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

if get_text is removed it will give the whole tag

```html
<span class="business--telephoneNumber" itemprop="telephone">01430 422826 </span>
```

i only need the insed phone number.

update - latest code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv

data_list=[]
url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=farmer&location=leeds'
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    }
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
soup = bs(site.content, 'html.parser')
questions = soup.select('.businessCapsule--mainContent')
for question in questions:
    busname = question.find(class_='businessCapsule--name').get_text()
    bustype =   question.find(class_='businessCapsule--classification').get_text()
    busnumber = question.select_one('span.business--telephoneNumber').text
    print(busnumber)
    new_data = {"busname": busname, "bustype": bustype, "busnumber": busnumber}
    data_list.append(new_data)
with open ('selector.csv','w') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = ["busname", "bustype", "busnumber"], delimiter = ';')
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in data_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Your example in not a complete Minimal, Reproducible Example. As there is both code and input data missing. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example    However i would guess that `question.find('span', {'itemprop': 'telephone'})` returns None in some iteration, but i don't know what you are iterating over since i don't know what **questions** contains.

Comment: Sorry, it said nnot to paste the full code, i have edited the code to the full page :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a different parent in order to select the appropriate child and change your selector for the child as shown below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=farmer&location=leeds'
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    }
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
soup = bs(site.content, 'lxml')
questions = soup.select('.businessCapsule--mainContent:has(span.business--telephoneNumber)')
for question in questions:
    print(question.select_one('span.business--telephoneNumber').text)
```

If you check this different parent selector you will see it selects the entire box with info in so you can then select your various children

[image]

If that is too retrictive you can test if tel was present

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=farmer&location=leeds'
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    }
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
soup = bs(site.content, 'lxml')
questions = soup.select('.businessCapsule--mainContent')
for question in questions:
    tel = question.select_one('span.business--telephoneNumber')
    if tel is None:
        tel = 'Not present'
    else:
        tel = tel.text
    print(tel)
```

Comment: That worked to strip the span yet it still gives the same error. `01430 422826 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscraper2.py", line 20, in <module>
    busnumber = question.select_one('.business--telephoneNumber').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
`

Comment: it still gives the same error for some reason although it is removing the span tag? ```0113 286 6060 
0113 256 9027 
0113 281 3009 
01430 422826 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscraper2.py", line 16, in <module>
    busnumber = question.select_one('span.business--telephoneNumber').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ```

Comment: One moment then

Comment: i have uploaded the full new code at the bottom of the original question if that helps? am i doing something else wwrong maybe? thank you for your help aswell :D

Comment: I've edited to select for only those listings with a telephone number It is using bs4 4.7.1.

Comment: yes it does work, it seems to be something after that? why would that number not save to the csv? im lost now haha